# Editing bibliography style file

Tags: bibliographies, texlive, ieeetran, thesis, bibliographystyle

I am using `IEEEtran` as the bibliography style file and compiling using texlive in ubuntu. The output has some undesired formatting which I wish to rectify by editing the `.bst` file for the bibliography style.
The issues to rectify are the use of a period instead of a comma for the separation of fields; the uneven spacing before the publisher's name of the books; the use of dash for repeated author names as in the following figure.

[image]

What are the necessary editing in `IEEEtran.bst` to rectify these problems?

Comment: It's for the Ph. D. thesis I am submitting to the institute. The institute thesis format uses `IEEEtrans` and my supervisor asked to change it as I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Your question can be devided into two:

1. Not repeating the same author
2. Changing the comma to a period.

Regarding 1. The default in `IEEEtran.bst` is to dash repeated author names. This can, however, be controlled and cancelled. `IEEEtran.bst` offers several controls that can be used to change the bibliography with a special cite command: `bstctlcite` that uses a special bib entry `IEEEtranBSTCTL`.

Check whether your `bib` file has an article entry such as this

```
@IEEEtranBSTCTL{e:BSTcontrol,
CTLdash_repeated_names = "no"
}
```

Turn the `"no"` into a `"yes"`, and make sure you cite this entry at the beginning of the document using `\bstctlcite{e:BSTcontrol}`.

As for 2: This requires that you edit your `bst` file.

Find the output function `FUNCTION {output.nonnull}` and replace the coman in

```
swap$
  prev.status.punct punct.comma =
     { "," * }
     { skip$ }
   if$
```

to

```
swap$
  prev.status.punct punct.comma =
     { "." * }
     { skip$ }
   if$
```